# This action is unauthorized 403

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am getting the following error when trying to call the API using the POST Request(http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/authors).
This action is unauthorized.
**Below is my routing list image**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzzkp.png)
**Below is the response I found in the body in POSTMAN**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Forbidden</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
        html {
            line-height: 1.15;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
        }

        body {
            margin: 0
        }

        a {
            background-color: transparent
        }

        code {
            font-family: monospace, monospace;
            font-size: 1em
        }

        [hidden] {
            display: none
        }

        html {
            font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, Noto Sans, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol, Noto Color Emoji;
            line-height: 1.5
        }

        *,
        :after,
        :before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 0 solid #e2e8f0
        }

        a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: inherit
        }

        code {
            font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, Liberation Mono, Courier New, monospace
        }

        svg,
        video {
            display: block;
            vertical-align: middle
        }

        video {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto
        }

        .bg-white {
            --bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: #fff;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--bg-opacity))
        }

        .bg-gray-100 {
            --bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: #f7fafc;
            background-color: rgba(247, 250, 252, var(--bg-opacity))
        }

        .border-gray-200 {
            --border-opacity: 1;
            border-color: #edf2f7;
            border-color: rgba(237, 242, 247, var(--border-opacity))
        }

        .border-gray-400 {
            --border-opacity: 1;
            border-color: #cbd5e0;
            border-color: rgba(203, 213, 224, var(--border-opacity))
        }

        .border-t {
            border-top-width: 1px
        }

        .border-r {
            border-right-width: 1px
        }

        .flex {
            display: flex
        }

        .grid {
            display: grid
        }

        .hidden {
            display: none
        }

        .items-center {
            align-items: center
        }

        .justify-center {
            justify-content: center
        }

        .font-semibold {
            font-weight: 600
        }

        .h-5 {
            height: 1.25rem
        }

        .h-8 {
            height: 2rem
        }

        .h-16 {
            height: 4rem
        }

        .text-sm {
            font-size: .875rem
        }

        .text-lg {
            font-size: 1.125rem
        }

        .leading-7 {
            line-height: 1.75rem
        }

        .mx-auto {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto
        }

        .ml-1 {
            margin-left: .25rem
        }

        .mt-2 {
            margin-top: .5rem
        }

        .mr-2 {
            margin-right: .5rem
        }

        .ml-2 {
            margin-left: .5rem
        }

        .mt-4 {
            margin-top: 1rem
        }

        .ml-4 {
            margin-left: 1rem
        }

        .mt-8 {
            margin-top: 2rem
        }

        .ml-12 {
            margin-left: 3rem
        }

        .-mt-px {
            margin-top: -1px
        }

        .max-w-xl {
            max-width: 36rem
        }

        .max-w-6xl {
            max-width: 72rem
        }

        .min-h-screen {
            min-height: 100vh
        }

        .overflow-hidden {
            overflow: hidden
        }

        .p-6 {
            padding: 1.5rem
        }

        .py-4 {
            padding-top: 1rem;
            padding-bottom: 1rem
        }

        .px-4 {
            padding-left: 1rem;
            padding-right: 1rem
        }

        .px-6 {
            padding-left: 1.5rem;
            padding-right: 1.5rem
        }

        .pt-8 {
            padding-top: 2rem
        }

        .fixed {
            position: fixed
        }

        .relative {
            position: relative
        }

        .top-0 {
            top: 0
        }

        .right-0 {
            right: 0
        }

        .shadow {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06)
        }

        .text-center {
            text-align: center
        }

        .text-gray-200 {
            --text-opacity: 1;
            color: #edf2f7;
            color: rgba(237, 242, 247, var(--text-opacity))
        }

        .text-gray-300 {
            --text-opacity: 1;
            color: #e2e8f0;
            color: rgba(226, 232, 240, var(--text-opacity))
        }

        .text-gray-400 {
            --text-opacity: 1;
            color: #cbd5e0;
            color: rgba(203, 213, 224, var(--text-opacity))
        }

        .text-gray-500 {
            --text-opacity: 1;
            color: #a0aec0;
            color: rgba(160, 174, 192, var(--text-opacity))
        }

        .text-gray-600 {
            --text-opacity: 1;
            color: #718096;
            color: rgba(113, 128, 150, var(--text-opacity))
        }

        .text-gray-700 {
            --text-opacity: 1;
            color: #4a5568;
            color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--text-opacity))
        }

        .text-gray-900 {
            --text-opacity: 1;
            color: #1a202c;
            color: rgba(26, 32, 44, var(--text-opacity))
        }

        .uppercase {
            text-transform: uppercase
        }

        .underline {
            text-decoration: underline
        }

        .antialiased {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
        }

        .tracking-wider {
            letter-spacing: .05em
        }

        .w-5 {
            width: 1.25rem
        }

        .w-8 {
            width: 2rem
        }

        .w-auto {
            width: auto
        }

        .grid-cols-1 {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr))
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg)
            }

            to {
                transform: rotate(1turn)
            }
        }

        @keyframes spin {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg)
            }

            to {
                transform: rotate(1turn)
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes ping {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1);
                opacity: 1
            }

            75%,
            to {
                transform: scale(2);
                opacity: 0
            }
        }

        @keyframes ping {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1);
                opacity: 1
            }

            75%,
            to {
                transform: scale(2);
                opacity: 0
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes pulse {

            0%,
            to {
                opacity: 1
            }

            50% {
                opacity: .5
            }
        }

        @keyframes pulse {

            0%,
            to {
                opacity: 1
            }

            50% {
                opacity: .5
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes bounce {

            0%,
            to {
                transform: translateY(-25%);
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.8, 0, 1, 1);
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.8, 0, 1, 1)
            }

            50% {
                transform: translateY(0);
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1);
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1)
            }
        }

        @keyframes bounce {

            0%,
            to {
                transform: translateY(-25%);
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.8, 0, 1, 1);
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.8, 0, 1, 1)
            }

            50% {
                transform: translateY(0);
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1);
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, .2, 1)
            }
        }

        @media (min-width:640px) {
            .sm\:rounded-lg {
                border-radius: .5rem
            }

            .sm\:block {
                display: block
            }

            .sm\:items-center {
                align-items: center
            }

            .sm\:justify-start {
                justify-content: flex-start
            }

            .sm\:justify-between {
                justify-content: space-between
            }

            .sm\:h-20 {
                height: 5rem
            }

            .sm\:ml-0 {
                margin-left: 0
            }

            .sm\:px-6 {
                padding-left: 1.5rem;
                padding-right: 1.5rem
            }

            .sm\:pt-0 {
                padding-top: 0
            }

            .sm\:text-left {
                text-align: left
            }

            .sm\:text-right {
                text-align: right
            }
        }

        @media (min-width:768px) {
            .md\:border-t-0 {
                border-top-width: 0
            }

            .md\:border-l {
                border-left-width: 1px
            }

            .md\:grid-cols-2 {
                grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))
            }
        }

        @media (min-width:1024px) {
            .lg\:px-8 {
                padding-left: 2rem;
                padding-right: 2rem
            }
        }

        @media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) {
            .dark\:bg-gray-800 {
                --bg-opacity: 1;
                background-color: #2d3748;
                background-color: rgba(45, 55, 72, var(--bg-opacity))
            }

            .dark\:bg-gray-900 {
                --bg-opacity: 1;
                background-color: #1a202c;
                background-color: rgba(26, 32, 44, var(--bg-opacity))
            }

            .dark\:border-gray-700 {
                --border-opacity: 1;
                border-color: #4a5568;
                border-color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--border-opacity))
            }

            .dark\:text-white {
                --text-opacity: 1;
                color: #fff;
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--text-opacity))
            }

            .dark\:text-gray-400 {
                --text-opacity: 1;
                color: #cbd5e0;
                color: rgba(203, 213, 224, var(--text-opacity))
            }
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="antialiased">
    <div
        class="relative flex items-top justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 sm:items-center sm:pt-0">
        <div class="max-w-xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="flex items-center pt-8 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0">
                <div class="px-4 text-lg text-gray-500 border-r border-gray-400 tracking-wider">
                    403 </div>

                <div class="ml-4 text-lg text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                    This action is unauthorized. </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Below is my routing file of my API  api.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthorsController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->prefix('v1')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/user', function(Request $request){
        return $request->user();
    });

   
    Route::apiResource('/authors', AuthorsController::class);
   
});
```

**Below is my  AuthorsController.php, I added in show method only return 'Test'**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Author;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreAuthorRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateAuthorRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\AuthorsResource;

class AuthorsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return AuthorsResource::collection(Author::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreAuthorRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreAuthorRequest $request)
    {

        return 'Test';
       /*  $author = Author::create([
            'name' => 'John Doe'
        ]);
        return new AuthorsResource($author); */
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Author  $author
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Author $author)
    {
       // return $author;
       return new AuthorsResource($author);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Author  $author
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Author $author)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\UpdateAuthorRequest  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Author  $author
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateAuthorRequest $request, Author $author)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Author  $author
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Author $author)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**last but not least, I am starting my routing list here in the bewlow**
| Domain | Method    | URI                                     | Name                              | Action                                                                    | Middleware                                     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                                       |                                   | Closure                                                                   | web                                            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/authors                          | authors.index                     | App\Http\Controllers\AuthorsController@index                              | api                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api           |
|        | POST      | api/v1/authors                          | authors.store                     | App\Http\Controllers\AuthorsController@store                              | api                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/authors/{author}                 | authors.show                      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthorsController@show                               | api                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api           |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/v1/authors/{author}                 | authors.update                    | App\Http\Controllers\AuthorsController@update                             | api                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api           |
|        | DELETE    | api/v1/authors/{author}                 | authors.destroy                   | App\Http\Controllers\AuthorsController@destroy                            | api                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/user                             |                                   | Closure                                                                   | api                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api           |
|        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/authorize                         | passport.authorizations.authorize | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize       | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | POST      | oauth/authorize                         | passport.authorizations.approve   | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController@approve  | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | DELETE    | oauth/authorize                         | passport.authorizations.deny      | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\DenyAuthorizationController@deny        | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/clients                           | passport.clients.index            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser                | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | POST      | oauth/clients                           | passport.clients.store            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@store                  | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | PUT       | oauth/clients/{client_id}               | passport.clients.update           | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@update                 | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | DELETE    | oauth/clients/{client_id}               | passport.clients.destroy          | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@destroy                | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/personal-access-tokens            | passport.personal.tokens.index    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | POST      | oauth/personal-access-tokens            | passport.personal.tokens.store    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | DELETE    | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id} | passport.personal.tokens.destroy  | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/scopes                            | passport.scopes.index             | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ScopeController@all                     | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | POST      | oauth/token                             | passport.token                    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests |
|        | POST      | oauth/token/refresh                     | passport.token.refresh            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/tokens                            | passport.tokens.index             | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | DELETE    | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                 | passport.tokens.destroy           | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web                                            |
|        |           |                                         |                                   |                                                                           | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate               |
|        | GET|HEAD  | sanctum/csrf-cookie                     |                                   | Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController@show                | web                                            |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+

Comment: Can some one please help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to make it more easy to read. Please don't just copy paste whole response.

Comment: I think you forgot to authorize.

Comment: Are you logged in while making a request ?

Comment: whats in your middleware? is there any check related to token?

Comment: I authorized and logged using Bearer  token in still getting the same

Comment: I hope this is middle ware ---->  App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:api

Comment: Any one in stackoverflow able to help this?